# Remove null from Laravel resources collection

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-resource

I build a Laravel API using `resources`. It return a `collection` plus some extra meta data.  I want to remove the `null` item(s) without losing my formatted `JSON` response.
Note: I tried `filter` method but it removed "data" and "extra_meta" from the `JSON` response. In other word it altered the `collection` heavily and it didn't just removed `null` item(s).

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "data_1": "some data"
        },
        {
            "data_1": "some data"
        },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    "extra_meta": {
        "meta_1": "some meta"
    }
}
```

Here is a simplified code using `resource`

```php
       return $collection = someResource::collection($somthing)->additional([
            'extra_meta' => [
                'meta_1' => $request->metaInfo,
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: Rather than trying to remove them, why don't you look at stopping them from being in the collection in the first place. Why are `null` values coming through?

Answer (score 0):

@Mano.

In php docs we have a function called `array_filter()`, if you use it like this:

```
echo (array_filter($data, function($value) { return !is_null($value) && $value !== ''; }))
```

The function `array_filter()` when its used with no callback (the second parameter) remove all null keys in array, but you can customize the function apllying a callback like the code above where i put a function that return only things that is not null and different than ''.

Hope i helped you.

EDIT: i recommend you to put the data array in a separated variable

```
$data = <json response>['data'];
```

after this use the function,

see the PHP docs here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Collection is an object not array and I cant use your recommendation to create a separate array 'data' then filter it then rejoin it with the 'extra_meta' since this will make the response extremely slow. I rather stick to the null value over your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        $data = [
            'order_items_price' => $this?->order_items_price,
            'order_items_quantity' => $this?->order_items_quantity,
            'key'=> null_data_will_appear,
        ];
          /** Add this filter */
        return array_filter($data, fn($data) => $data != null);
    }
```